# JavaScript: Use Prototype Method inside Class to Console Log ### in Place of Letters in Array

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, prototype

I want to take the following array and turn it into a sequence of ##### using array method.  Note: I'm using a prototype method inside a class.

```
this.secretWord = ['e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 't']
```

Below is my code:

```
getSecretWordPuzzle () {
    let newArr = []; 
    return this.secretWord.map((elem) => {
      let finalStr = newArr.push('#')

      console.log(finalStr)
    })
  }
```

My output is:

```
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

My desired output is: `'########'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the `map` function, so it is considered as undefined. That's why you're getting an array of undefineds.

Comment: How about `'#'.repeat(this.secretWord.length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a value, not push to an array; map returns a new array:

```js
const secretWord = ['e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 't']
const getSecretWordPuzzle = () => secretWord.map(_ => '#')

console.log(getSecretWordPuzzle())
```

Or, use a foreach and return the array, using your approach:

```js
const secretWord = ['e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 't']

function getSecretWordPuzzle() {
  let newArr = [];
  secretWord.forEach(() => newArr.push('#'))
  return newArr
}

console.log(getSecretWordPuzzle())
```